# Put arguments on separate lines PyCharm

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I've been searching high and low and I can't seem to find a way to enable / create an intention in PyCharm to put function arguments on separate lines.

Using `context action` -> `Alt + Enter` on MacOs, with the code below

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func sumThree(a int, b int, c int) int {
    return a + b + c
}

func main() {
    sumOfThee := sumThree(1, 2, 3)
    fmt.Println(sumOfThee)
}
```

I can do this in GoLand:

[image]

But how do I execute the same action in PyCharm i.e. with `Alt + Enter`?

With this code, there's no such action:

```python
def sum_three(a: int, b: int, c: int):
    return a + b + c


sum_of_three = sum_three(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

I get this:

[image]

I've searched the options but there seems none to be available for Python:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't available yet in PyCharm, please see and follow the corresponding issues: [PY-45729](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-45729) plus relates to section.